# How does Pusher handle delivering messages to backgrounded iOS applications

Tags: ios, pusher

Pusher seems like a good fit for what I want to do, but the only thing that I can't figure out is how Pusher handles delivering a message to an iOS device that the application is not currently running on/backgrounded. I was really hoping that Pusher would fallback to push notifications through APNS and GCM (for Android), but I can't find any mention of that. How does Pusher handle delivery to backgrounded/not running applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Pusher only uses the websocket connection and doesn't fall back to native push (APNS / GCM) when the app isn't running.

More info: https://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/faq-common-requests/is-pusher-a-push-notification-service

Comment: I found another service that I believe handles socket connection failover with push http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/mobile/

Comment: In iOS yes, PubNub falls back to APNS, but in Android it doesn't use GCM, so it forces you to implement a Service that is run on boot. See this Knowledge Base answer: [Can my Android App Receive Messages While Inactive?](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21720011-Can-my-Android-App-Receive-Messages-While-Inactive-)

Comment: Thanks again. That is very helpful to know. Knowing this, I may just write my own socket server that manages pubsub and dropped client failover to APNS and GCM. Doing this may make it easier to use a standard like XMPP as my chat protocol. Would you happen to know of any other services or software that would do what what I described so I don't have to rewrite the wheel :)

Comment: I just found that Google Cloud Messaging has a service called [Cloud Connection Server (CCS)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html). May be useful for delivering messages to Android devices.

Comment: It seems like Parse is a good option for cross platform push notifications using GCM/ APN
https://parse.com/products/push
Haven't tested it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, but it pops up on the google, so lets update the answer.

at the time of the question, the accepted answer ([jcugat's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21190776/3880796)) , I assume, was correct.
but now, it is not.

both services, [Pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/push_notifications) and [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/products/mobile-push/) now support fall backing to Google's GCM/FCM on android and Apple's APN on ios for sending push notifications.